# Why am I seeing duplicate questions on the stack overflow landing page?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It is the first time I have seen this. Is it a bug?

Example:

[image]

Comment: [reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEtSS.png)

Answer (score 13):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

I introduced a busted comparison in a refactor of some homepage algorithms that lead to the set of ["random questions"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) being included twice if they *also* ranked highly for you.